# How can I suspend, checkpoint and resume ARMv8 processes on my Mac M1?

Tags: macos, arm, apple-m1, armv8

I am writing ARMv8 assembly and running it on my Mac M1 to solve problems such as the Travelling Salesman. These programs can run for a long time (several days or weeks).

Is there any way I can suspend these processes, save their state to disk and resume them later? This would be helpful in case I have to use my machine for something else or if the machine crashes for some reason.

My assembly programs are very simple and only use registers and stack memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No simple way, but there is a somewhat easy way.

[Install a VM](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/07/how-to-use-free-virtualization-apps-to-safely-test-the-macos-ventura-betas/?amp=1)

Then resume or suspend when you need to be running the application.